# Adding customXML part to Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I am trying to add a custom XML part to Word. What I am doing is I have generated an XML model that binds all my data in the Word file. This is how I am trying to fill it, but nothing is being added:

```
public void FeedCustomXmlParts(MyModel model, string xmlns)
{
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyModel), xmlns);
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ser.Serialize(ms, model);
        CustomXmlPart partLabel = GetCustomXmlPart(_wordDoc.MainDocumentPart, xmlns);
        ms.Position = 0;
        partLabel.FeedData(ms);
        ms.Flush();
    }
}

private static CustomXmlPart GetCustomXmlPart(MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart, string targetNs)
{
    if (mainDocumentPart == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mainDocumentPart));
    }

    return (from part in mainDocumentPart.CustomXmlParts
        let xElement = part.GetXDocument().Root
        where xElement != null
        let ns = xElement.GetDefaultNamespace()
        where ns == targetNs
        select part).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I understand that you want to add custom XML parts to the word.

The following code example adds a custom XML part to a specified document.

```
    private void AddCustomXmlPartToActiveDocument(Word.Document document)
{
    string xmlString =
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
        "<employees xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/vsto/samples\">" +
            "<employee>" +
                "<name>Karina Leal</name>" +
                "<hireDate>1999-04-01</hireDate>" +
                "<title>Manager</title>" +
            "</employee>" +
        "</employees>";

    Office.CustomXMLPart employeeXMLPart = document.CustomXMLParts.Add(xmlString, missing);
}
```

For more information, please refer to:[To add a custom XML part to a Word document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-custom-xml-parts-to-documents-by-using-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2017)

Hope that helps!